# ASP.NET web forms is not allowing multiple concurrent requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My ASP.NET web forms 4.6.1 application is not allowing multiple simultaneous requests per client.

Per other answers to this question, I have turned off sessionState; note that I turned off enableSessionState and sessionState in web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <pages enableSessionState="false">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="sitemap.xml" type="Sitemapify.SitemapifyHttpHandler, Sitemapify" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState mode="Off"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
```

I do have Microsoft Application Insights turned on.  Also, for context here is what my request headers look like:

```
:method: GET
:path: /default
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1869881177.1514609561; ai_user=XeZcX|2018-05-05T19:57:07.457Z; _gid=GA1.2.328414536.1530944373; fs_uid=fullstory.com`B3VK1`5639445604728832:5743229060251648; _gat_gtag_UA_111731780_1=1; ai_session=SEXQU|1531086456703|1531087024595.8
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
```

What seems to be happening is that there are a lot of images in some of my pages and until those images load it won't let the user navigate to another page.

Does anyone have any idea why it would block on one request at a time to load?

Comment: `is not allowing multiple simultaneous requests per client.` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @mjwills I have noticed that while one page is loading in a browser I cannot open another page until that first page finishes loading.  If I do open a second page in Chrome, for example, that second page will show as "pending" until the first page loads